# How to increase maximum open files Mac OSX 10.6 for neo4j graph database?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, neo4j

I am getting this error message when starting my local neo4j server for development (live I am using the heroku neo4j addon).

```
WARNING: Detected a limit of 2560 for maximum open files, while a minimum value of 40000 is recommended.

WARNING: Problems with the operation of the server may occur. Please refer to the Neo4j manual regarding lifting this limitation.
```

I have googled, tried to search the manual on site, downloaded and searched the pdf.  (To hopefully eliminate the RTFM responses).  I cannot find how to do this in Mac OSX 10.6.  Sounds like something pretty basic that it's just assumed I'll know.  Any thoughts?

Comment: This might be a better question on the Apple SE site. Flag if you'd like me to migrate. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm... I preferred it when there was one place to ask questions and get smart answers - stackoverflow... now it seems that you have to figure out where to ask the qs and all of them have fewer people in to answer them... I don't know where is the right place to ask what any more.

Comment: I feel your pain :) I'm not pressuring you. There was a flag raised suggesting that Apple.SE might get better eyes. I'll throw the question at the Apple (and the Unix) mods and see what they think.

Comment: @RichardJordan [so] is for programming question, this is a system administration question.

Comment: There is a consensus that unix.SE might be best for this. Flag if you want to migrate it.

Comment: Since these are unix limits, Unix.SE is certainly fine, but launchd is more a Mac centric daemon even though it's open sourced by Apple - the majority of users are on OSX. I'll certainly watch over it if you send it our way to Ask Different. And Richard, as you see - some questions have no homes and some several, but no site covers all questions someone wants to ask ;-)

Comment: Did I do this right - flagging it?  I will defer to whoever knows best where it should be asked, just transfer it over if you think best - not something I know how to do.  As it is I'm just going to try the answer posted below.

Comment: Have you seen http://ghickman.co.uk/2012/02/25/osx-max-files-limit-neo4j.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to change this would be to set the resource limits in a launchd.plist format and use that to spawn your development shell or your database process. Once you have your launchd job, you can load, unload and have the system start it up and respawn it as needed.

See man launchd.plist - look for:

```
 HardResourceLimits <dictionary of integers>
 Resource limits to be imposed on the job. These adjust variables set with setrlimit(2).  The follow-
 ing keys apply:

       NumberOfFiles <integer>
       The maximum number of open files for this process.  Setting this value in a system wide daemon
       will set the sysctl(3) kern.maxfiles (SoftResourceLimits) or kern.maxfilesperproc
       (HardResourceLimits) value in addition to the setrlimit(2) values.
```

I've also had good luck with the published guides and [blogs for Oracle 10g installs](http://blog.rayapps.com/2009/09/14/how-to-install-oracle-database-10g-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard/) as they explain fairly well what sysctl and kernel values Oracle likes to change on Snow Leopard (and other releases) since Lion is a bit more launchd centric than past releases and you indicated a 10.6  for your base OS.